# lambda to function conversion in python

Tags: python, lambda, min

I am trying to convert a labda function in normal function but unable to understand it.

```
def closest(u): 
    return min(updated_unique_list, key=lambda v: len(set(u) ^ set(v)))
```

how this labda and min works?
I tried to understand from docs but I want to understand with this example and to create a normal function instead of this lambda function.

Comment: from python help

min(...)
    min(iterable[, key=func]) -> value
    min(a, b, c, ...[, key=func]) -> value

    With a single iterable argument, return its smallest item.
    With two or more arguments, return the smallest argument.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`min`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#min) find the minimum value of an iterable with respect to a function. `min(lst, key=func)` in Python can be roughly considered as <sub><sup>(ignoring details like calling `f` as little as possible or walking through the list only once)</sup></sub>

```
retval = lst[0]
for item in lst:
  if func(item) < func(retval):
     retval = item
return retval
```

In your case, it finds the item `v` in `updated_unique_list` such that `len(set(u) ^ set(v))` is minimum.

Now, `^` between two set is their [symmetric difference](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set.symmetric_difference). `set(u) ^ set(v)` returns a set of elements that does not appear in both `u` and `v`. The size of the result will be zero if `u` and `v` are equal, and is maximum if they do not overlap at all.

Therefore, the function tries to find an object in the  `updated_unique_list` which has the most common elements with `u`.

If you want the "normal function" just expand the `min` according to the algorithm I've described above.

Comment: thanks.what us this f(items)? can u explain me in terms of updated_unique_list= ["page", "text", "footer", "header", "title", "good morning"]  and u="those"

Comment: @sam: Sorry I meant `func(item)` (corrected). Apply the key function to each item. In your case `func("page")` would become `len(set("page") ^ set("those"))`.